# json file Parse error on line . Expecting 'EOF' but it looks perfect

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql

This is my json file:

```
{"_id":3,"date_created":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","date_updated":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","name":"Computers","slug":"Computers","description":"Computers","meta_description":"Computers","meta_keyword":"Computers","navigation":"true","top_id":3,"top":"true","parent_id":2,"parent":"Default","active":"y","iscrawlable":"n","productype":"simple","path":"Computers","categoryids":"2,3","children":"yes","ebaycat":58058},
{"_id":4,"date_created":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","date_updated":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","name":"Home & Office","slug":"Home & Office","description":"Home & Office","meta_description":"Home & Office","meta_keyword":"Home & Office","navigation":"true","top_id":4,"top":"true","parent_id":2,"parent":"Default","active":"y","iscrawlable":"n","productype":"simple","path":"Home & Office","categoryids":"2,4","children":"yes","ebaycat":0},
{"_id":5,"date_created":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","date_updated":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","name":"Entertainment","slug":"Entertainment","description":"Entertainment","meta_description":"Entertainment","meta_keyword":"Entertainment","navigation":"true","top_id":5,"top":"true","parent_id":2,"parent":"Default","active":"y","iscrawlable":"n","productype":"simple","path":"Entertainment","categoryids":"2,5","children":"yes","ebaycat":550},
{"_id":6,"date_created":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","date_updated":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","name":"Motors","slug":"Motors","description":"Motors","meta_description":"Motors","meta_keyword":"Motors","navigation":"true","top_id":6,"top":"true","parent_id":2,"parent":"Default","active":"y","iscrawlable":"n","productype":"simple","path":"Motors","categoryids":"2,6","children":"yes","ebaycat":0},
{"_id":7,"date_created":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","date_updated":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","name":"Fashion","slug":"Fashion","description":"Fashion","meta_description":"Fashion","meta_keyword":"Fashion","navigation":"true","top_id":7,"top":"true","parent_id":2,"parent":"Default","active":"y","iscrawlable":"n","productype":"simple","path":"Fashion","categoryids":"2,7","children":"yes","ebaycat":3082},
{"_id":8,"date_created":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","date_updated":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","name":"Health","slug":"Health","description":"Health","meta_description":"Health","meta_keyword":"Health","navigation":"true","top_id":8,"top":"true","parent_id":2,"parent":"Default","active":"y","iscrawlable":"n","productype":"simple","path":"Health","categoryids":"2,8","children":"yes","ebaycat":0},
{"_id":9,"date_created":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","date_updated":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z","name":"Electronics","slug":"Electronics","description":"Electronics","meta_description":"Electronics","meta_keyword":"Electronics","navigation":"true","top_id":9,"top":"true","parent_id":2,"parent":"Default","active":"y","iscrawlable":"n","productype":"simple","path":"Electronics","categoryids":"2,9","children":"yes","ebaycat":279},
```

Using Jsonlint.com Constantly I receive error

> Parse error on line 22: ...  "ebaycat": 58058},{    "_id": 4,
>   ----------------------^ Expecting 'EOF'

and focuses error in this area

```
},
{
```

similar situation happens when I use MongoVue import json documents from file function.

any help or reference to a validation tool (with fixing function) appreciated.

Comment: remove last `,` and cover whole thing with `[ ]` then it should parse to an array

Comment: @TRiNE thanks, but i want to insert different documents in a collection, not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several objects which are represented by `{...}`
Those objects should be on another object or array. Remove your last comma `,` and cover whole thing with `[ ]` to parse it as array of objects.

**EDIT**
Just saw `MongoVUE`. Then simply put all documents without commas like

{..}
{..}

and try